# Turn objects/controls to black and white

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-11

In IE8 there is a function called DX Filter, which provides various multimedia-style visual effects to your Web page.

Most of them can easily replaced by CSS but there's still one that's killing me. It's the `XRay` filters, with the following syntax :

```
<!-- This DIV is the target container for an image.  -->        
<DIV ID="oDiv" STYLE="position:absolute; left:270px; color:tan;" >
   An Image - >    
   <IMG SRC='/workshop/graphics/earglobe.gif' />
</DIV>
<BUTTON onclick=" oDiv.style.filter=
   'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(XRay=1)'">
Show XRay</BUTTON><BR/>
<BUTTON onclick="oDiv.style.filter=''">Clear Filter</BUTTON><BR/>
```

It can make any controls/objects like : buttons, tab headers, images ... to turn like x-ray images, for example :

```html
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <button type="button">I'm normal</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:black;color:white">I turned x-ray</button>
      <br />
   </body>
</html>
```

But since IE-10, this function is not available anymore.

How can we achieve this effect's result in IE-11 using CSS and Javascript?

Comment: Could you post a screen shot for us non-IE users?

Comment: @Turnip I'm sorry, I will post a screen shot as soon as I finish installing a virtual machine for runing IE-8

Comment: CSS3 has a "filter" property https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/ that can be used to specify "grayscale" and make things black and white, but of course IE is as usual way behind the curve http://caniuse.com/#search=filter so you can't really use it.

Answer (score 0):

The invert filter is not supported in IE 11. I believe you could use an SVG filter though as that is supported in IE10+. However, SVG is not supported in IE8 so if you are trying to support older versions of IE it might require separate markup in conditional comments (or some alternate approach).

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the SVG filter doesn't support CSS in IE11, only in-line syntax, how can I declare one filter and apply it for all the pages in my project?

Answer (score 0):

You would do this sort of thing in standard CSS using the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter%20/) property. However, that's not supported in IE11! (it's only in Edge, behind a flag) I think the only way you could do it is by drawing the image to a canvas element and adjusting the colours yourself.